# Scrapy response comes all dirty and xpath doesn't work

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

how are you?
My Scrapy's response comes all dirty as can be seen in the image below and no xpath works. In spider I just did the authentication, send the request and showed the response.body.
How to proceed?

Scrapy Response:

[image: Image Scrapy Response]

Comment: You response HTML is pretty good. What XPath did you try?

Comment: //table/tbody[tr[td[b[contains(text(), "Nome do Plano")]]]]/tr

Comment: On Elements of Chrome, this xpath it works. 
On scrapy no.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom

Answer (score 1):

The most common error working with XPath and tables is that **modern browsers automatically add tbody tag to the DOM**. That's why you need to always check source code before using any tags.

Try it without `tbody`:

```
//table[.//tr[td[b[contains(text(), "Nome do Plano")]]]]/tr
```